# Drupal AHAH forms empty data

Tags: drupal, cck, ahah

I have a drupal website with a multi cck field (or how is it called? when you can "add another" field with ahah).

The problem is, when I click add another, everything works fine, but if I wait 5 minutes or so, and I click again, all the ahah fields disapear.

My post is done correctly, but my data response, which should contain the html of the fields, is empty.

Does anyone have an idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

In ahah form use, the form is loaded from the cache "form_get_cache()". Every 3 minutes a cron jub runs, and clears the cache, that's why the from can't be retrieved and is empty.